# How change cell position in staticTableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting, static

How programmatically change cell position in staticTableView?

I have TableView with static cells and one section.
I want to change order of cells from second row when I press the button which changes alphabetical to from big to small order.

Comment: You could have the first row as a section headers and then use the `sort` function on the array or dictionary you have for data source and reload the tableview.

Comment: i have staticTableView and don't use array

Comment: It would be easier if you add it to an array, sorting, ordering and setting the rows for the table.

Comment: In prototype cells type i could't create that i want

Comment: https://www.simplifiedios.net/custom-uitableviewcell-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non static tableView with UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

or

use 2 staticTableView, with the 2 alphabetical order, and when you press button hide first tableView and set the second visible. When you press again toggle tables visibilities.